# Simple Boolean Switch directive not working as expected

Tags: angularjs

I have created a simple "Switch" button directive that allows the user to flip a switch on/off using a boolean value.  For some reason I cannot get the directive to update the boolean model that is sitting on ngModel correctly.

Please take a look http://jsfiddle.net/nvymLokf/

```
app.directive('skSwitch', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            'ngModel' : '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.ngModel);
            if(scope.ngModel === true && attrs.skSwitch === 'true'){
                elem.parent().find('button').removeClass('selected');
                elem.addClass('selected');         
            }else if(scope.ngModel === false && attrs.skSwitch === 'false'){
                elem.parent().find('button').removeClass('selected');
                elem.addClass('selected');   
            }

            elem.on('click', function (e) {
                elem.parent().find('button').removeClass('selected');
                elem.addClass('selected');

                switch (attrs.skSwitch) {
                    case 'true':
                        scope.ngModel = true;
                        break;
                    case 'false':
                        scope.ngModel = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        scope.ngModel = attrs.skSwitch;
                        break;
                }
                 scope.$apply(); // HAD TO ADD THIS
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/nvymLokf/1/

Ah! I knew I was doing something dumb... I am not too new to Angular so I should have caught this before.  I needed to use `scope.$apply()` after changing the `scope.ngModel` value.  I thought that since I am in an Angular directive, Angular would continue to digest the scope. But my guess is since I am using an isolated scope I needed to use apply() to tell Angular to update the UI.

Just curious, is there a way to do this without an isolated scope and without using $apply()?

Comment: That's the right logic but the wrong reason. It isn't because your in a isolate scope. It's because your change happens in a jquery callback. The .on('click', function...  Angular won't know anything about when jquery callbacks get fired and doesn't update.

Comment: If you didn't want to manually call a digest the. You would need to provide a template and use ng-click instead or use ngModal as a controller instead of a binding. See https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-using-ngmodel-in-custom-directives

Comment: Seems overkill for a boolean - http://jsfiddle.net/devitate/sj9z5L6u/

Comment: @Dylan I see what you mean, but I am trying to make a directive that can be used all over the application with any number of `sk-switch` directives